# Extract substring bash

Tags: regex, bash

i have this string:

```
4017de9511f7    workflow-engine-ms    0.12%     4.609MiB / 7.574GiB  0.06%         29MB / 15.8MB     4.1kB / 0B          13
```

I have to extract the number 4.609, how can I do it in bash?
thx!!

Comment: Not an exact dupe. The reference question and answers have nothing to do with further splitting the desired field further.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way using `awk` and `sprintf` would be:

```
awk '{val=sprintf ("%g",$4); print val}' file
4.609
```

Using the `"%g"` conversion specifier, simply converts the `4.609` portion of the 4th field, ignoring the MiB characters.

Answer (score 0):

If the format does not change, you can use `sed -e 's#  *# #g' | cut -d\  -f4 | cut -dM -f1` to extract the value.

The `sed` joins subsequent spaces into one, the first cut extract the 4.609MiB field, and the second one strips of the MiB.

Answer (score 0):

If by 'I have this string' you mean, you have it in some file and you need to grab first match of X.XXX Mib (or GiB, or kB), I've solved that like this:

```
echo "4017de9511f7    workflow-engine-ms    0.12%     4.609MiB / 7.574GiB  0.06%         29MB / 15.8MB     4.1kB / 0B          13" > test
```

to prepare test file, and

```
grep -Po "[0-9\.]+(?=(Mi|Gi|k))" test | head -1
```

to find matching string